# How to convert two columns in a row having a range value to multiple incrementing rows based on the range

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have two columns in a row which have range values. eg: `from_series: 100` and `to_series: 110`. Now I need to convert these to multiple rows.

```
name value from_series to_series
 aaa  32      100        110
```

I need to convert as shown below:

```
name value series
 aaa  32     100
 aaa  32     101
 aaa  32     102 until 110
```

Comment: paste what have you tried to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I think this code snippet should work where df is your dataFrame.

```
  df.rdd.flatMap{row=>
    val name = row.getAs[String]("name")
    val value = row.getAs[Int]("value")
    val fromSeries = row.getAs[Int]("from_series")
    val toSeries = row.getAs[Int]("to_series")
    (fromSeries to toSeries).map(seriesValue=>(name,value,seriesValue))
    }
```